# alert box isn't raised in the code, its written for conform msg

Tags: angularjs

function

```
        FController($scope,$window)
        {
           $scope.persons=[];
             $window.alert("hi in body");

           $scope.saveIt = function () {
              $window.alert("alert in save");
             //$scope.persons.push({    });

           }; 
         }

      <button  id="bt1" ng-Click="saveIt()">Save</button>
```

Comment: Have you tried `alert("alert in save")` without `$window.`?

Answer (score 0):

`$window.alert` is not correct. `window.alert` is. You don't need to include $window in your dependency injections.